# Quisiera saber si ¿Jqwidgets cuenta con combobox multi select?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

Hola tengo un par de combobox creados con la libreria de Jqwidgets y todo esta muy bien funcionan correctamente... 
Actualmente el combobox permite seleccionar solo una opcion a la vez
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es que me han pedido que modifique la estructura del combo para que me permita seleccionar mas de un registro a la vez
 Anteriormente utilice un selector de Bootstrap que me permitia hacerlo este es el ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe si puedo agregar alguna propiedad o algo al combobox hecho con Jqwidgets para conertirlo en multiselect como el segundo ejemplo? 
Este es el codigo para cargar el combobox

```
$('#jqxdropdownlist').jqxDropDownList({
    filterable: true,
    source: dataAdapterruta,
    displayMember: "ruta",
    valueMember: "pk",
    width: 200,
    height: 25
});
```

De antemano muchas gracias.. Espero su ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr esto con la propiedad multiselect.

Como puedes ver en la API (https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxcombobox/jquery-combobox-api.htm):

```
$("#jqxComboBox").jqxComboBox({multiSelect: true });
```

Habilita el modo de selección múltiple.

Ten en cuenta que deberás usar el método "getSelectedItems" (en lugar de "getSelectedItem") para obtener las opciones seleccionadas:

```
var items = $("#jqxComboBox").jqxComboBox('getCheckedItems');
```

Puedes encontrar un ejemplo de uso en http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/JLVdF/.

Un saludo y espero que sirva.